# Server query to YouTube API “is there any YouTube video containing this specific word?” - if so, what is the link, upload date etc

Tags: api, video, youtube, youtube-data-api

Do you think we could use the **YouTube Data API** to get to know which products have any YouTube review/video. **Then paired with our system** via, for instance, Video Name?

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear. However, you want to try this.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#try-it
You can set type to snippet and q to the words you want to search for.

Comment: Could you rather give a (little) explanation and not only post the link?